# quick tip on \input or \include?

Tags: miktex, tex-core, input, include, ebook

I'd been trying to compile a pdf from a tex file, using only miktex texworks. But it turned out that the file(gutenberg 38769) was too big to be loaded at all on some devices and so I am now attempting to write short \input or \include tex to avoid all the waiting, crash, etc. Can you give me an example that would substitute the whole thing(ie the grand ebook) with relatively short commands? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE ! // You can find some introduction here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project . // Don't hesitate to search for input, include and the tags input and include here ;-)

Comment: \input and \include are to join chunks of the document, but it seems what you want really is to  split a PDF. Then the right tool is `pdftk` without TeX,  or  `pdfpages` with TeX.

Comment: as Fran says, neither input nor include will help making smaller PDF or ebook.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i think the `OP` is about split a huge tex file to multipls small ones.

Comment: You can try with notepad++.